# unable to find entry point named mkl_aa_fw_get_workdivision in dll mkl_core.dll

Tags: python, machine-learning, intel-mkl

I'm currently starting the Udemy Machine Learning A-Z course, but I am experiencing some difficulties getting my Python 3.6.3 environment running smoothly.

When running the Simple Linear Regression code, that uses Scikit-Learn, Pandas, Numpy and matplotlib, my Spyder displays the error:

> unable to find entry point named mkl_aa_fw_get_workdivision in dll mkl_core.dll

as noted in the title, and the console says "Kernel died, restarting".

I tried downloading the new version of MKL, reinstalling my Anaconda and mkl packages but nothing seems to work. Below is my current setup just for good measure:

Intel Xeon E5520 2.27GHz
12GB Ram DDR3
Nvidia Quadro Fx 3800
Samsung 850 EVO 250 GB
Windows 7 Professional SP1

Thanks for all the help, sorry for any post mistakes, this is my first time doing this.